# ¿Por qué no cambia la imagen de fondo del body?

Tags: javascript, html

Intento cambiar la imagen del fondo del `<body>` onLoad. Mi código es el siguiente:

```js
document.body.addEventListener('load', function () {
    document.body.style.backgroundImage = 'url("https://images2.alphacoders.com/130/1301855.jpg")';
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>DOM y Eventos</title>
</head>
<body>
    <button id="miBoton">Haz clic aquí</button>
    <div id="miDiv"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

¿Est
a algo mal?, y si es así, ¿por qué el evento no funciona?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Porque realmente `body` no cuenta con un evento `load`, este evento pertenece a un conjunto denominado [Window-reflecting body element event handler set](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/webappapis.html#window-reflecting-body-element-event-handler-set), que vendría siendo *«Eventos del `body` que se reflejan en `window`»*, lo que quiere decir que realmente es el objeto `window` el que cuenta con este evento y por esto que `addEventListener` no funciona

Entonces esto funciona:

```
window.addEventListener('load', function () {
  document.body.style.backgroundImage = 'url("https://images2.alphacoders.com/130/1301855.jpg")';
});
```

Cuando el evento es seteado como atributo esta reflección se hace automaticamente.

Entonces estos códigos tambien funcionan:

```
document.body.onload = function () {
    document.body.style.backgroundImage = 'url("https://images2.alphacoders.com/130/1301855.jpg")';
});
```

o directamente en el HTML

```
<body onload="init()">
```

Por otro lado, otra forma (creo que incluso mejor) es usar [DOMContentLoaded](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/DOMContentLoaded_event)

```
  document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", (event) => {
    document.body.style.backgroundImage = 'url("https://images2.alphacoders.com/130/1301855.jpg")';
  });
```

---

Los eventos que se trasladan al `window` son:

- blur
- error
- focus
- load
- resize
- scroll
- scrollend

Comment: Muchas gracias por el aporte, fue una explicación clara y precisa.

Answer (score 0):

Lo que entiendo es que quieres que al hacer click cambie el fondo, si es eso con este código funciona.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>DOM y Eventos</title>
</head>
<body>
    <button id="miBoton">Haz clic aquí</button>
    <div id="miDiv"></div>

    <script>
    const btn = document.getElementById('miBoton');
    btn.addEventListener('click', function () {
        document.body.style.backgroundImage = 'url("https://images2.alphacoders.com/130/1301855.jpg")';
    })        
    </script>

</body>
</html>
```

Si lo quieres es con el evento load, tu imagen no carga debido a que según la documentación

> El evento load se dispara cuando toda la página se ha cargado,
> incluyendo todos los recursos dependientes como hojas de estilo e
> imágenes. Esto contrasta con DOMContentLoaded, que se dispara en
> cuanto se ha cargado el DOM de la página, sin esperar a que los
> recursos terminen de cargarse.

Lo que puedes hacer es esto:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>DOM y Eventos</title>
</head>
<body>
    <button id="miBoton">Haz clic aquí</button>
    <div id="miDiv"></div>

    <script>
    document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
        document.body.style.backgroundImage = 'url("https://images2.alphacoders.com/130/1301855.jpg")';
    })        
    </script>

</body>
</html>
```

Espero haberte ayudado. Saludos.